# Why is there a Bounty option for an Answered Question

Tags: support, bounty

Why does a question still have the:

> start a bounty

field lit up, as the question has been marked as answered?

Example:

- [Is Gmail for business still free](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/is-gmail-for-business-still-free)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) which describes in depth how the bounty system works. In essence, the answer to your question is that

> **all bounties are completely independent of and unrelated to accepting an answer**.

The idea is to get people to have another look at a question if it hasn't had enough attention. Even if the original poster accepted an answer as "good enough".

See also these rules for the rewarding of the bounty from the [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> - If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created *after* the bounty started
>     with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If
>     there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to
>     anyone.
> - If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer *during the bounty period*, and the bounty
>     expires without an explicit award – we assume the bounty owner liked
>     the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the
>     time of bounty expiration.

Comment: yet another reason is to reward the existing answer(s)

Comment: Has this been a proven concept? Will it not diminish the effect of the bounty itself?

Comment: @Sathya only if the answer is marked accepted *in* the bounty period, being upvoted doesn't count for existing answers. @ Jacob The system has been in place over 2 years, it would likely have been changed if it didn't work. Typically questions with a bounty will attract new answers from bounty hunters, albeit with some who just spam them in the hope they win.

Comment: anyone can start a bounty on an existing question and manually reward a bounty on any answer, even if it was posted prior to the bounty period. We do this on [su] few times. The mechanism John talks about is the auto-bounty allocation. /cc @JacobJanTuinstra

Comment: Good point @Sathya, I hadn't seen them used that way before.